# max14830 with beaglebone black

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack

I have started to learn the how to access linux driver from userspace

Is there any example code for max14830 with beaglebone black using max310x driver.

And is any api is there for max310x drievr and how to controlle the extra gpio pins of max14830

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 1):

You should use set the pin configuration in the .dts file and load the system. After loading the device tree file. You should see device with the following command.

```
cat /sys/bus/spi/devices/*/modalias
spi:max14830
```

and in the device tree compatiable machine. It should match with "maxim,max14830".

```
max14830@0 {
               compatible = "maxim,max14830";
               reg = <0>; /* cs0 */
               mode=<0>;
               spi-max-frequency=<1000000>;
```

Comment: MAX14830 ID 0xff does not match , MAX14830 is connected and with dts

Comment: in /sys/bus/spi/devices/*/modalias iam getting max14830 but it is not showing in /dev ttymax getting error in dmesg "MAX14830 ID 0xff does not match , MAX14830 is connected and with dts " where to edit the _REV_ID or after it detects the MAX14830 it will send the REV ID need clarification with this.

Comment: hi,we are using MAX14830(SPI to QUAD Uart). MAX14830 IC is connected to SPI1 of beaglebone black. We have enabled the driver in the Linux and written DTS for max14830. Linux beaglebone 4.19.6-bone-rt-r10 In /sys/class/gpio gpiochip496 is created and we able to create 16 gpio and it is working but ttyMAX0-3 is not creating in dmesg ttyMAX0-3 it is comming but in /dev it is not showing